# Avahi-daemon troubles

Tags: cpu, avahi

I did a clean install (keeping my old home partition) of Ubuntu 12.04. Everything working fine, except the process avahi-daemon is consuming a lot (60-90%) CPU.

What is the avahi-daemon? Does it have something to do with Ubuntu One? I found guides on the internet on how to disable it, but I'm not eager to disable it, as it apparently has use.

Hardware: Dell Studio 1557, intel i5, AMD Radeon HD5470

Answer (score 3):

Avahi is a free Zero Configuration Networking (Zeroconf) implementation, including a system for multicast DNS/DNS-SD service discovery. It allows programs to publish and discover services and hosts running on a local network with no specific configuration. For example you can plug into a network and instantly find printers to print to, files to look at and people to talk to. It is licensed under the GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL). (Source: [Wikipedia: Avahi (software)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_%28software%29))

You could try to restart the daemon by following:

Open up a terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>) and type: `sudo service avahi-daemon restart.`

Comment: Hmm, so disabling it is a bad idea probably. It doesn't matter if I restart it or not. I'll probably best file a bug report for this.

Comment: @RVH: This could have been an [instance of LaunchPad Bug #1059286](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/avahi/+bug/1059286).  Seems that this was reported at around the time this was originally posted.  It's supposed to be fixed now, and I'm no longer seeing this on Ubuntu `18.04.2`.  However, I am seeing similar behavior on Raspbian `9` "`stretch`" with `avahi-daemon` eating up a high percentage of CPU after leaving it on for a while.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why, but toggling WiFi off and then back on fixed this for me when the top answer (`sudo service avahi-daemon restart`) did not.

Update: it's because I connected to a different network. Still not sure why that makes a difference, but if you can, try switching.

Maybe the answer will come up [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=922630)?

(Ubuntu 19.04)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, one of my laptops uses a USB to RJ45 device. Once in a while (at least today it happened), when closing the laptop, the RJ45 may go berserk and start sending millions of packets non-stop. So fast and so bad that even Wireshark could not do anything about it and as you mentioned Avahi was going crazy (in my case it used around 33% CPU).

My WiFi would show the issue by not being able to keep up with the very high traffic, so as a result: no WiFi. (I have a similar issue when sending UDP packets on my network to handle some video system I'm working on). Note that did not completely kill the LAN network. I guess that's the *advantages* of having a 1Gbit switch...

To find the one connection that caused the problem, I had to disconnect each computer and see whether it "fixed" the WiFi. The WiFi itself was fine once that one laptop RJ45 was disconnected. I suspect that the USB device had just enough electricity from the RJ45 to continue to work when it should instead have been turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're networking via wifi to other devices, just remove it totally with: "sudo apt-get remove avahi-daemon" - you'll be glad you did, for it *can* occasionally be a glitchy piece of work...

I've had problems with Avahi since Ubuntu 17.10 just trashing my wifi and disabling it requiring a reboot to get wifi back online. Just installed Lubuntu 18.04.5LTS on another laptop, and it began messing with my wifi on that computer too...

I also believe it can be a security risk allowing unauthorized computers to mess with my wifi. Occasionally I'd have two (2) sets of wifi bars in the panel - weird! Other times it would drop wifi, reload, drop again and not be able to reload without rebooting. I have no use for it at all...

I'm sure it can be valuable to some, but to novice users it can become an ongoing nightmare!!!